# How to get a value from user properties inside java request sampler code

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to access a value from the user properties which is in jmeter/bin form java request sampler. I could find no method in the JavaSamplerContext. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are we talking about "Java Request" or "JSR223"? You want to get an value from user.properties file?

Comment: @Mercy Is your question resolved?

Answer (score 2):

[JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) is your friend

How about

```
JMeterContextService.getContext().getCurrentSampler().getProperty("property.name.here");
```

See [here](http://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/ajax-sampler.git) for example usage of [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/).

Comment: your links are wrong. It won't show any useful usage.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this problem, using JMeter, version 3.2, and the [Lazery Maven JMeter plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin), version 2.2.0.  This is a really nice plugin, by the way.

I had custom properties defined in my POM.xml file, one being:

```
<propertiesUser>
    <integration.environment>
        ${integration.environment}
    </integration.environment>
</propertiesUser>
```

I used the following code in a Java Sampler extending AbstractJavaSamplerClient.  In the runTest method, I did this:

```
JMeterVariables variables = JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables();
String intEnv = variables.get("integration.environment");
```

Is there a better way?